# Search through a table with user input

Tags: user-input, sql-like

This is my script:

```
select * from cliente 
where NOME_CLIENTE like (Upper('&supplier_name') || '%');
```

and it all gives me "no rows selected".
Why does this happen? And how to fix it?

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you provide more information. According to the results, the query runs successfully.

Comment: What I wanted to do is check if a name is in the "Cliente" table, if it is, then show me the record

Comment: Right, what is your input and what is expected output. Did you try with the hard coded input? Is 'no rows' expected?

Comment: My input is "LADEL LDA" and the output should be something like this " 12 LADEL LDA                                C  881113653 493840471508895778563", the same when you do select * from Cliente where nome_cliente = 'LADEL LDA';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description, you need to have the wildcard '%' before the user input as well, here is the example:

```
select * from cliente 
where NOME_CLIENTE like ('%' || upper('&supplier_name') || '%');
```